# How to send most up-to-date value from the state before the browser is closed?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, setinterval

It's 2 am, and I think it is time for a stupid question. So, if I have a setInterval() code running that would send a value update to the server every certain amount of time (10 secs, 1 min). If the browser is closed or the user navigates away from the page, is there a way to send the value update to the server with the up-to-date value before the user leaves? And can anyone recommend what I should look up for a topic like this? I am unsure how to look up this part of the event loop. TIA!

Comment: For the record, recommendations for things are technically not for this forum. But since it's 2AM, have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event Do read up on which of the unload events is applicable to your app, since they can be inconsistent.

Comment: You're probably looking for something like `window.onbeforeunload` but I'm not sure if this would work in your case.